# [Done]: reopen e If you get sent home early (for no fault of your own) should you still get paid for the time?

Tags: discussion

[If you get sent home early (for no fault of your own) should you still get paid for the time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182463/if-you-get-sent-home-early-for-no-fault-of-your-own-should-you-still-get-)

An edit has been made to this post making it a general question as opposed to a company specific question. It is a good question for contracting, ethics, and work etiquette, and IMO should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

It was at 3 Reopen votes when I saw it - I agree that the edit brings it into much better shape so I've re-opened.